# How do I prove a modified version of Riesz' lemma?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T: X \to X$ a continuous linear operator, $S = I - T$ where $I$ is the identity on $X$. Let $Y \subsetneq Z \subseteq X$ be closed linear subspaces such that $S(Z) \subseteq Y$. Then there exists an $x_0 \in Z \setminus Y$ such that $\Vert x_0 \Vert = 1$ and
$\inf_{y \in Y} \Vert Ty - Tx_0 \Vert \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

My question is: How do I prove this? I was told that it can be proven similarly to Riesz' lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $T = I-S$. Then you get

$$\lVert Tx_0 - Ty\rVert = \lVert (I-S)x_0 - (I-S)y\rVert = \lVert x_0 - \underbrace{(Sx_0 + y - Sy)}_{\in Y}\rVert.$$

Now you can just use the standard Riesz lemma.